# About a strange word named "degenerate class" when reading dalvik-bytecode

Tags: java, android

In the article at [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html)， there is a strange word named "degenerate class".
It is in the description for the bytecode "**const-class vAA, type@BBBB**".

And the description is :

**Move a reference to the class specified by the given index into the specified register. In the case where the indicated type is primitive, this will store a reference to the primitive type's degenerate class.**

What the mean of this strange/amazing word？Is this answer like int.class or Integer.class?

Hope someone can tell me the mean of this word，thank very much。At the same time，forgive my poor English：）。Have a nice day， Everyone!